# "adb -r install /package.adb" deosn't restart aplication on device

Tags: android, adb

I can use all adb features, but when i try to `adb -r install /package.adb` it just gives me:

> "2858 KB/s (4116553 bytes in 1.406s)"

and thats it, nothing happens. When I do it on another computer it deploys application and restarts it. What can be wrong?

Comment: Are both computers using the same version of the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this command after your install:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n your.package/.possibleSubfolder.MyMainActivity
```

Comment: yes it is working after editing package name, but loads old version of application witch is deployed before.

Comment: maybe adb doesn't copy code at all? How could it be possible.

Comment: Remove all installed versions and try again. Changing package names is always combined with trouble so make sure you get everything cleaned up before you continue